# Select object and recalculate normals via script?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, export, import

I have a script that allows to import and export `.obj` files which is working fine. However, I'd like to perform some operations in between these calls, for example *select the mesh* and *recalculate the normals* (outside). If I try that, I get a *context error* and I'm not sure why...?

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect

```
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=source_to_file)
    
    print("Starting--------------------------------------------")
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
        # go edit mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        # select al faces
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        # recalculate outside normals 
        bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)
        # go object mode again
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    print("Ending--------------------------------------------")
    
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=target_to_file,use_materials=True)
```

How is it possible to know the object imported by any operator (there is no return value) and how can I recalculate the normals per object that is triggered by a button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`bpy.context.selected_objects[:]`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selected_objects) to get all imported objects. Iterate through the list, set the select state of each object to `True` and make it the *active object* as well in order to call operators like [`mesh.normals_make_consistent()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=normals_make_consistent#bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent):

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=source_to_file)
obj_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects[:]

for obj in obj_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    # go edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    # select al faces
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # recalculate outside normals 
    bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)
    # go object mode again
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

**Blender 2.7x**

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=source_to_file)
obj_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects[:]

for obj in obj_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    # go edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    # select al faces
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # recalculate outside normals 
    bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)
    # go object mode again
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Updated .blend file can be found here:

[image]

Comment: I have this error: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects' (I use 2.78a)

Comment: @D.Giunchi Could you provide your whole script to be able to debug it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vpyi29Nq , I also used obj_objects = [ o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.select ] but I got the first error.

Comment: @D.Giunchi I tried this http://pasteall.org/225375 and it's working totally fine with no errors

Comment: in the console I can see this: location: <unknown location>:-1
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\fix.py", line 73, in <module>
  File "\fixpy", line 52, in main
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect

location: <unknown location>:-1

Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

<!> event has invalid window

Comment: @D.Giunchi what are the lines 73 in 52 in your script?

Comment: 52 is bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') , the other is the main that call. I discover that using another obj it seems to work. The weird thing is that when I run the script I see in blender that the obj that is loaded and selected and I can change the mode to edit with the combo.  I uploaded the obj here http://filebin.ca/3AqCDhS3JUuI

Comment: @D.Giunchi as shown here http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=111981 it's working perfect with me.

Comment: really don't know what to think, if I used the script with your change I get this error: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects' , I have a windows 10, 64 bit...maybe should I try in a Virtual Machine, don't know what;s going on.

Comment: @D.Giunchi send me your .blend file

Comment: @D.Giunchi the file you sent doesn't include the script. Please provide the complete file with script and everything causing the error.

Comment: actually you don't need the blend, since I open blender and simply run the script but I put everything here: http://filebin.ca/3AsCCCCsBnJu

Comment: I tried also in virtual box (linux mint) and I force my friend to run it and he got the same error :(

Comment: @D.Giunchi check this file http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45346

Comment: it works this one, I did several tries... like removing the model and run the script. But what I miss to do to have a blend like this? My workflow was, open blender, open the script ,run it.

Comment: @D.Giunchi It looks like the problem is in the .blend file. I'll update my answer and provide the .blend file if you can accept and upvote.

Comment: works for me, but probably I miss something to do for let blender knows the context or something like this

Comment: @D.Giunchi Obviously, The problem is in your .blend file

Comment: maybe I got it, it was the reset_blend function, it cleared too much and lost the context. Many Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Making normals outside can also be done with the bmesh module operator [`recalc_face_normals(bm, faces)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals)

Sample script

```
import bpy
import bmesh

from bpy import context

#bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=source_to_file)
bm = bmesh.new()
meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects
            if o.type == 'MESH')
for mesh in meshes:
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)
    bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm, faces=bm.faces)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bm.clear()
    mesh.update()
    
bm.free()
#bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=target_to_file, use_materials=True)
```

Saves the need to flip mode and context object.

Comment: I would upvote this answer 5 times if I could... I hate using the ops functions...