# How to work with Bmesh correctly?

Tags: python, bmesh

I'm writing a window generator script.

Here is a current version of my script:
https://gist.github.com/romanvolodin/3bfd349795443118a2298819349a0b3c

Windows config:
https://gist.github.com/romanvolodin/60055b1593a3c4c6d52e017cfd9696be

Script's algorithm looks like this (in short):

- Read json config
- Build a wall object
- Build window's inner part
- Get vertex normals on the edge of a window
- For every window build window's decoration

In my scene I have a mesh object ('profile') which is define the decor profile.
[image]

To build a window decor, I copy given profile several times to window vertex position and orient it in vertex normal direction.

[image]

And then I bridge them together. Kind of 'profile along path'.

I have a super weird bug - the most of the time I get distorted geometry. Something corrupt my normal's data. But sometimes the script works correctly (at 0:07, 1:06, 1:28, 1:37, 1:45, 2:12):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6wysGzIQfU

Also, only 4 windows at the beginning are distorted, 5th and next look just nice. (These crumpled objects at the origin are four first windows.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is more.

In my script I [print](https://gist.github.com/romanvolodin/3bfd349795443118a2298819349a0b3c#file-window_from_json-py-L456) normal's positions. 
Then I [add](https://gist.github.com/romanvolodin/3bfd349795443118a2298819349a0b3c#file-window_from_json-py-L463) a new Bmesh object. 
And then I [print](https://gist.github.com/romanvolodin/3bfd349795443118a2298819349a0b3c#file-window_from_json-py-L467) normal's positions again.

```
    # ...
    windows_edge_normals = get_windows_edge_normals(windows_vertex_positions)

    for i, window_normals in enumerate(windows_edge_normals, start=1):
        print("before", i)
        for num, normal in enumerate(window_normals):
            vert_co, vert_normal = normal
            print(
                "   co: {}\n"
                "normal {}".format(vert_co, vert_normal)
            )

    for i, window_normals in enumerate(windows_edge_normals, start=1):
        print("after", i)
        bm = bmesh.new()
        last_profile = None
        for num, normal in enumerate(window_normals):
            vert_co, vert_normal = normal
            print(
                "   co: {}\n"
                "normal {}".format(vert_co, vert_normal)
            )
    # ...
```

And the result is completely different! (Note: 'before' is green and on the right, 'after' red on the left, see link) https://www.diffchecker.com/9YEV3moY

Why?! I've just added a new Bmesh!

**So the question is** - what I'm doing wrong? Should I delete previous bmeshes explicitly (the wall and inner parts)? Or it's a bug in Blender?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are placing the trim profile simply rotated 45º at the bottom corners of the windows that will inevitably lead to distortions. That is a geometry problem, not a bug in your code. See related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe

Comment: Please see the video. The corners are ok, but first 4 windows not.

Comment: Looking good. Try updating normals [example1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/99297/15543) [Example2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72687/15543)

Comment: I've tried to add bm.normal_update() right after bm = bmesh.new() (line 463) and here is what I've got: when I start fresh Blender and run my script the first time, I get no errors. On next runs I get glitches just like described above. It looks like a memory issue.

Comment: Hi, to look into this issue I'd need run the code inside Blender. Could you make all files available to reproduce the error?

Comment: Hey Campbell! Glad to see you =) Here it is https://yadi.sk/d/xiSzFY5ALyZXzw

Comment: @ideasman42 Did you find anything interesting?